# setInterval run fast after 5-7 minutes

Tags: jquery, setinterval, preloader

Why does `setInterval` run very fast after some time? I used the code
below for a background slideshow on my site. I also use the [fullpage preloader plugin](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/).

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow IMG:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 9999);
});

//use fullpage preloader
QueryLoader.init();
```

I want to repeat the animation every 9999 milliseconds. But after some time (5-7 minutes), the animation seems to repeat every 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: What do you mean by "after some time"? Is the actual flow of things accellerating, or are just the animations falling behind from the beginning and after a while they start to overlap?

Comment: As a side note, you should use `setInterval(slideSwitch, 9999)` instead of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the javascript function setInterval() returns a handle

```
handle = setInterval("slideSwitch()", 9999);
```

that you can clear whenever you want with [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

```
function killInterval(){
   clearInterval(handle);
}
```

So you'd have to clean your interval after some time, for that you want to use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

```
setTimeout("killInterval()",3000);
```

Comment: `setTimeout(clearInterval(handle),3000);` makes no sense. the first parameter to setTimeout should be a function.

Comment: Ok, at least that works now. :) But doesn't it seem a little strange to clear an interval by creating another one? In any case, how does this answer the question?

Comment: Oh well, I misread. The title says "setInterval run fast after 5-7 minutes" so my answer would be the way to clear the previous interval, and then he could have created another one with another frequency. But the question is **why** setInterval runs faster after 5-7 minutes, I wouldn't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make sure that one animation doesn't interrupt the previous one in a way you're not intending:

```
...
$next.css({ opacity: 0.0 })
     .addClass('active')
     .stop() // <-- new line
     .animate({ opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
         $active.removeClass('active last-active'); 
     });
```

Comment: how can i repeat slideshow every 9999 miliseconds with above code?     thanks for reply

Comment: @Rajnikant: I've just added a single line to your code, and provided a couple of unchanged lines for context. The rest of your code should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval will run the function every 9999 milliseconds, not once.

setInterval will repeat, setTimeout will run once.

You need to use setTimeout.

Comment: and how is this answer connected to the question? he implemented a slideshow, so he must either use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` with recursion!

Comment: yes i want to reapet animation every 9999 milisecond but after some time setInterval time decreased(for exa:9999, after 5-7 min 1000 milisecond) let me know solution thanks for reply

Comment: you should add this comment to your question, as this makes it clear!

Comment: Must have misread, Thought i saw the setInterval in the slideSwitch() function.